# AMD 5600H Power Management Options for 22.04

Tags: power-management, 22.04, amd-ryzen

I have an HP Pavilion laptop with an AMD Ryzen 5 5600H processor and Nvidia graphics card. While I am able to set Nvidia into power saving mode, I do not have any option to do so for my processor. I get 5 hours plus in Windows 10 during power-saving mode but only close to 3 hours in 22.04.

I am using `Auto CPU Frequency` to extend battery life now. But would be great if there is any option, native AMD or otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: Some patches for Ryzen's power managing are in linux 5.17

Comment: How to make use of that? Thanks.